If we need the mean and variance of the entire batch for batch normalization, how do we do a single forward pass before we get these values?
If I understand correctly the model has various hidden layers with batch normalization layers in between. When trying to compute a forward pass to back-propagate, how do we know what mean and variance the BN layers should have? Do we just apply normalization for a specific instance?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
